# How do I convert excel file with n worksheets into n csv files?

Tags: python

Is there a way to convert the worksheets in an excel file into a number of csv files?

Comment: Don't know the exact answer but this can be a start - http://www.python-excel.org/

Comment: Search is a good start, also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747501/getting-data-from-an-excel-sheet and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459788/get-the-inputs-from-excel-and-use-those-inputs-in-python-script.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  There is.

1. `xlrd` will allow you to read a spreadsheet.  http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd
2. `csv` will allow you to write CSV files.  http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

This happened to me so often, that I uploaded a spreadsheet reader library to SourceForge.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/stingrayreader/.

Answer (score 0):

xlrd is fine but won't handle the newer excel format (xlsx). (yet)

One alternative, on a windows machine with excel installed, is to use the Python/COM interface to drive excel.

A similar approach (but not reliant on platform and vendor) is to use Open Office to read the spreadsheet via its python api. An article with python script is: [Convert Spreadsheets to CSV files with Python and PyUno](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/convert-spreadsheets-csv-files-python-and-pyuno-part-1v2)

One gotcha: if you use the native 'save as', either of excel or OO, to do the conversion, you get the data **as formatted in the sheet**. (This is the approach used by the above OO solution and the usual excel/COM solution.) So numeric data, for example, will be rounded to the number of decimal places that excel would display. (For dates, this is usually a good thing, since you get the formatted date string, rather than the underlying numerical value.)